# How to build OpenCV using Cmake/Visual Studio in Debug mode without Python debug library

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCv 2.4.7 from source on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012 (vc11).
I have

- downloaded the sources from github
- switched to the 2.4.7 tag
- used cmake to configure and generate a VS solution
- run the BUILDALL target for Win32 in release mode and in debug mode

In release mode, I can build all with no problem .
However, when I attempt to build for debug mode I get the following error:

> Error   2   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib'    C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\LINK

I don't have a `python27_d.lib`, so I simply copied `python27.lib` to `python27_d.lib`, hoped for the best, and reran the cmake configuration (probably that last bit was pointless).

Now when I attempt to build I get these errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp**_Py_NegativeRefcount referenced in function "struct _object * **cdecl pycvCreateHist(struct _object *,struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?pycvCreateHist@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@00@Z)   C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp**_Py_Dealloc referenced in function "struct _object * **cdecl pycvCreateHist(struct _object *,struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?pycvCreateHist@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@00@Z)    C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp**_PyObject_DebugMalloc referenced in function "struct _object * **cdecl pyopencv_VideoCapture_VideoCapture(struct _object *,struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?pyopencv_VideoCapture_VideoCapture@@YAPAU_object@@PAU1@00@Z)  C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp**_PyObject_DebugFree referenced in function "void **cdecl Capture_dealloc(struct _object *)" (?Capture_dealloc@@YAXPAU_object@@@Z)  C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Py_InitModule4TraceRefs referenced in function "struct _object * __cdecl init_cv(void)" (?init_cv@@YAPAU_object@@XZ)   C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp**_Py_RefTotal   C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\modules\python\cv2.obj
>   Error   7   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals   C:\Users...\OpenCV\2.4.7\build\lib\Debug\cv2.pyd

Other than downloading the source for Python and making a debug build of it so I have a proper `python27_d.lib` (of which I think I have no other need), any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you check in your CMake build properties if you accidentally selected Python..? Search for `python` in the CMake GUI and deselect anything that comes up.

Comment: @scap3y thanks for the idea. So if I want to use Python with OpenCV I would have to make a release build with Python enabled, then reconfigure to disable Python and make the debug build? That should be ok as I think I would only ever want to use Python with the release build.

Comment: If you need Python, then it would be enabled for both. As far as I know, there is no such possibility where you can disable certain module linkages for each build.. What you could do, however, is to generate 2 different libraries (one with Python but for release and another without Python but Debug) and install them in different directories.

Comment: This is happening because the MSI installer from Python.org does not supply a debug version of the python lib file.  As you found copying the release version isn't working.  Seems like a glaring issue especially since they supply the PDBs and it's pyconfig.h that is trying to reference the python27_d.lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the OpenCv website you need to switch the Visual Studio project to release after you have used CMake. http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html

This can be done by right clicking the solution and clicking configuration manager to access this setting.

I have tested this with Visual Studio 2015 Community, OpenCV 3.2.0 and python 3.6 (Anaconda)

Answer (score 1):

find the pyconfig.h 
change

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
# define Py_DEBUG 
#endif
```

to

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
//# define Py_DEBUG 
#endif
```

chagne

```
# ifdef _DEBUG 
# pragma comment(lib,"python27_d.lib") 
# else 
# pragma comment(lib,"python27.lib") 
# endif /* _DEBUG */
```

to

```
# ifdef _DEBUG 
# pragma comment(lib,"python27.lib") 
# else 
# pragma comment(lib,"python27.lib") 
# endif /* _DEBUG */
```

modify object.h

```
#if defined(Py_DEBUG) && !defined(Py_TRACE_REFS) 
#define Py_TRACE_REFS 
#endif
```

to

```
#if defined(Py_DEBUG) && !defined(Py_TRACE_REFS) 
// #define Py_TRACE_REFS 
#endif
```

Comment: Thnaks, it is easier to just #undef _DEBUG for just including Python.h and then defining it again.